# Expand/Collapse all the gof kendoTreeList

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, dojo, telerik

I am using [kendoTreeList](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist/)

and I am trying to expand all the groups. Here is my [code sample](http://dojo.telerik.com/EJeZU)

But it seems like the kendoTreeList support only expanding the first group. I tried the following selector in the expand method as well.

treeList.expand($(".k-treelist-group")); to expand all the groups. Even though the selector $(".k-treelist-group").length is 3 (total number of groups) but the treelist only expand the first group.

Any suggestion please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right, according with the information on [their site](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist#methods-expand) it expands *the row* and not *the rows*.

Then you can iterate for getting the same effect:

```
var treeList = $("#treeList").data("kendoTreeList");
var rows = $("tr.k-treelist-group", treeList.tbody);
$.each(rows, function(idx, row) {
    treeList.expand(row);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#treeList").kendoTreeList({
    columns: [ "id", "name" ],
    loadOnDemand:false,
    dataSource: [
      { id: 1, parentId: null, name: "Group", age: 30 },
      { id: 2, parentId: 1, name: "John Doe", age: 33 },
      { id: 3, parentId: 1, name: "Johson", age: 33 },

      { id: 4, parentId: null, name: "Group 2", age: 30 },
      { id: 5, parentId: 4, name: "Doe ", age: 33 },
      { id: 6, parentId: 4, name: "Noomi", age: 33 },

      { id: 7, parentId: null, name: "Group 3", age: 30 },
      { id:8, parentId: 7, name: "Doe ", age: 33 },
      { id: 9, parentId: 7, name: "Noomi", age: 33 }

    ]
  });
  var treeList = $("#treeList").data("kendoTreeList");
  var rows = $("tr.k-treelist-group", treeList.tbody);
  $.each(rows, function(idx, row) {
    treeList.expand(row);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="treeList"></div>
```

Comment: It will be very slow when there will be thousands of records in that table so do you have any solution for this/

Comment: @DevendraSoni: Did you find any solution for the issue when there are thousands of records?

Answer (score 4):

If you expand many rows you can get into some performance issues, then one alternative to looping the .expand method is to modify the data and bind it again.

```
var treeList = $("#treeList").data("kendoTreeList");
var dataItems = treeList.dataSource.data();

$.each(dataItems, function(i, item) {
    item.expanded = true;
});

treeList.dataSource.data(dataItems);
```

You can also modify the data before it's bound.

```
dataSource: {
        data: [
        { id: 1, parentId: null, name: "Group", age: 30 },
        { id: 2, parentId: 1, name: "John Doe", age: 33 },
        { id: 3, parentId: 1, name: "Johson", age: 33 },

        { id: 4, parentId: null, name: "Group 2", age: 30 },
        { id: 5, parentId: 4, name: "Doe ", age: 33 },
        { id: 6, parentId: 4, name: "Noomi", age: 33 },

        { id: 7, parentId: null, name: "Group 3", age: 30 },
        { id:8, parentId: 7, name: "Doe ", age: 33 },
        { id: 9, parentId: 7, name: "Noomi", age: 33 }          
        ],
      schema: {
        parse: function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            item.expanded = true;
          });
          return data;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it helped me a lot performance-wise.

Comment: One drawback of the first method is if you have unsaved changes: calling `cancelChanges()` will restore the data to the state of the latest `dataSource.data(dataItems)` calls. If that's a problem, you must remember `_pristineData` and restore it later.